# AJAX - Aparecer divs

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Como faço para aparecer uma `div` no retorno do `AJAX`, por exemplo:

Escrevo no input um utilizador, e envia os dados por `AJAX` assim:

```
$("#botao").click(function(){
    var xprocesso = $("#segundo").val();

    $.post('aquirecebe.php',{processo:xprocesso},
        function(data)
        {
            $(".aparecerresultado").html(data);
        })

});
```

Na página que recebe os dados, faz uma verificaçao se o utilizador que procura existe.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE n_processo = '".$processo."'");

        if(!$sql)
        {
            echo '<script> swal("ERRO!", "Contacte o programador.", "error") </script>';
        }else
        {   
            $contar = 0;
            $contar = mysql_num_rows($sql);

            if($contar <= 0){
                echo '<script> swal("Oops","Pedimos desculpa, mas o utilizador não foi encontrado.","error") </script>';

            }else{
                echo '<script> swal("Sucesso!", "Utilizador encontrado. Pode prosseguir para o registo.", "success") </script>';

            }
        }
```

até aqui tudo ok. Agora queria que quando aparece a mensagem de sucesso (significa que foi encontrado um utilizador), que aparecer uma `div`. Como retorno o código `javascript` pelo `AJAX`?

Answer (score 3):

Enviar script para correr no lado do cliente não é muito bom. O melhor seria passares um JSON e teres alguma lógica no browser para fazer o que precisas. Deixo um exemplo com Sweet Alert e também com o que pedes: adicionar HTML com a resposta.

Por exemplo no PHP podias ter:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE n_processo = '".$processo."'");

if (!$sql) {
    echo '{"status": "ERR", "swal": ["ERRO!", "Contacte o programador.", "error"]}';
} else {
    $contar = 0;
    $contar = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if ($contar <= 0) echo '{"status": "OK", "existe": false, "swal": ["Oops","Pedimos desculpa, mas o utilizador não foi encontrado.","error"]}';
    else echo '{"status": "OK", "existe": true, "swal": ["Sucesso!", "Utilizador encontrado. Pode prosseguir para o registo.", "success"]}';
}
```

E depois no JavaScript:

```
$("#botao").click(function() {
    var xprocesso = $("#segundo").val();
    $.post('aquirecebe.php', {processo: xprocesso}, function(data) {
        var res = JSON.parse(data);

        // mostrar resultado via Sweet Alert
        swal.apply(swal, res.swal);

        // mostrar resultado via DIV
        var $resultado = $(".aparecerresultado");
        $resultado.html(""); // para apagar
        var titulo = $('<h3/>', {text: res.swal[0]}).appendTo($resultado);
        var texto =  $('<hspan/>', {text: res.swal[1]}).appendTo($resultado);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Existe várias formas de fazer isso, a mais comum seria dessa forma:

```
<div id="resultado" style="display:none;"></div>
<script>
$("#botao").click(function(){
    var xprocesso = $("#segundo").val();

    $.post('aquirecebe.php',{processo:xprocesso},
        function(data)
        {
            $("#resultado").css("display", "");
            $("#resultado").html(data);
        })

});
</script>
```

Dessa forma você pode estilizar sua div com css da forma que desejar.

Answer (score 1):

Você está retornando um script para aparecer dentro de um div, não entendi muito bem. Por que não retornar a mensagem de sucesso/erro como um simples HTML? Por exemplo:

```
<p>Mensagem de sucesso</p>
```

E ai na função de sucesso do Ajax você faz:

```
$(".aparecerresultado").html(data);
```

E assim vai aparecer o HTML retornado direto na div. Você pode usar CSS e formatar melhor para deixar a mensagem mais atraente para o usuário.